# UIView animateWithDuration artefact (blinking white vertical line on view)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have simple blinking animation for digits divider in digital clock.
views hierarchy looks like this:

- ClockBGView

  - StartButton
  - ClockView

When `StartButton` pressed `ClockView` become visible (it is over button) and starting animation of blinking digits divider every second. But some minutes after animation started there are appears blinking white line. You can see it on this video:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1680228/ANIMATION_ARTEFACT.MOV

```
- (void)updateTimer {
     NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timerStartDate];

    long seconds = lroundf(timeInterval); // Modulo (%) operator below needs int or long
    int hour = seconds / 3600;
    int mins = (seconds % 3600) / 60;

    self.clockHrsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", hour];
    self.clockMinLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", mins];

    (hour > 0) ? (self.clockHrsLabel.alpha = 1.0f) : (self.clockHrsLabel.alpha = 0.2f);

    // devider animation blink
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.clockDeviderLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL complete){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.clockDeviderLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
        }];
    }]; 
}
```

Is it a bug or feature? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem may be solved by two solutions..

> **FIRST IS:**
>
> i think timer is repeated again before your animation completes..
>   Basically you have two animations both have duration of 0.3 seconds.
>   so you can call timer method after every 1 sec because total animation
>   duration is 0.6

Or

> **SECOND IS:**
>
> dont use the timer and use following code....

```
- (void)updateTimer {
     NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timerStartDate];

    long seconds = lroundf(timeInterval); // Modulo (%) operator below needs int or long
    int hour = seconds / 3600;
    int mins = (seconds % 3600) / 60;

    self.clockHrsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", hour];
    self.clockMinLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", mins];

    (hour > 0) ? (self.clockHrsLabel.alpha = 1.0f) : (self.clockHrsLabel.alpha = 0.2f);

    // devider animation blink
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.clockDeviderLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL complete){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            self.clockDeviderLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL complete){
            [self updateTimer];
        }];
    }]; 
}
```

i am not sure but this code may help you....... best of luck

Comment: Yep, second variant absolutely fixed bug. I just add check flag for animation continues and increase every cycle to 0.5 to blink every second. I have no reputation to vote your answer yet, but great thanks to you!